# Different Validation for Different Forms - Asp.Net Web Core Applicaiton

Tags: c#, validation

in my view named SendSMS, i have

```
@ model SMS.Modelz.PlainFormz
```

In my other view named MyView I have

```
@ model SMS.Model.SomethingElse
```

in spite of these differences, it seems my view SendSMS is still validating based on SMS.Model.SomethingElse,  how do i force to validate on  (SMS.Modelz.Plainformz)

I have two view models, but it still validates based on the first :(

Comment: Are you using ModelState and Data annotations to validate your models? Share some more code such as views and controllers

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem, it was in my controller, 
I had

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendSMS(SomethingElse sms)
```

I needed to have

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendSMS(PlainFormz sms)
```

this was my model

```
namespace SMS.Models
{
public class SomethingElse
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the Temporary 
Password")]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 8, ErrorMessage = 
"Password should have at least 8 Characters")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Phone Number 
without the dashes")]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = 
"Phone Numbers should only contain 10 digits, and should be 
 entered without any dashes.")]
    public string Number { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and had other model for PlainFormz

```
namespace SMS.Modelz
{
public class PlainFormz
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Message")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Phone Number 
without the dashes")]
    [StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 10, ErrorMessage = 
"Phone Numbers should only contain 10 digits, and should be 
entered without any dashes.")]
    public string Number { get; set; }
  }
}
```